# Google Map Showing White Page With Google Logo xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Sir,

I have made an `Activity` Page to display map. For this I have done each and every step as guided on article linked as : [`http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-google-map-with-marker/`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-google-map-with-marker/)

When I have Builded & Deployed application on my android device, `Activity` page would be displayed fully white with `Google` logo at bottom left corner of screen, But no map displayed & also no error would be occured.

Why activity page is displayed fully white & why would map is not displayed?

Comment: Use Google Maps API v2 Key and ensure it is added to your AndroidManifest.xml file correctly.

Comment: Please make sure that Googles Map Android API is Enable or not
[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3blo3tlivph0ra5/Screenshot%20%289%29.png?dl=0)

Comment: How to check whether Google Map API is enabled or not ?

Comment: sir, [Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRdUtRczJEd095T2c) following image is the API service status screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google Map Showing White Page With Google Logo xamarin.Android

Please make sure Google Play Services in your device is available. If  the Google Play Services APK is not installed, your google map app will showing a blank page with Google Logo, exactly same with your situation.

**Check for Google Play Services** :

```cs
public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable ()
{
    int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable (this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
    {
        if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError (resultCode))
            msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString (resultCode);
        else
        {
            msgText.Text = "Sorry, this device is not supported";
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        msgText.Text = "Google Play Services is available.";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Calling this method in `OnCreate` method :

```cs
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    msgText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.msgText);

    IsPlayServicesAvailable ();
}
```

For more detail information, you could read this [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-gcm/#Check_for_Google_Play_Services).

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Maps API v2 Key and ensure it is added to your AndroidManifest.xml file correctly
AND ALSO
Make sure you add these permissions to the manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="com.deg.blubcnmobl.droid.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.deg.blubcnmobl.droid.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: Sir that I have already done. I have done every steps as it has been guided in that referenced article. API Key from Google Console & registration of Application, Enable of Android services, everything. But still map is not showed up.

Comment: Sir, in my `.axml` file I have declared `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`. Now would it be `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` OR `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` ?